# My children are useless. What should I do?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

I've been playing King's Bounty for a while now and have picked myself up a wife.
I was very surprised when she asked me to have a child, but since I did not want to upset her (luckily I don't apply this game-logic in the real world) I went along with it.

So after a while I embraced a new virtual babe, which took up one of my wife's equipment slots and gave me space for 8 additional scrolls in my spellbook - rather useless. This process repeated itself to produce an even worse offspring granting me +4 scrolls. That's when I decided to stop having children.

Now from what I gathered from a good friend of mine who played quite a bit, children can actually give excellent bonuses so I'm just amazingly unlucky. He also said that the only way to start over is to replace my wife, but that the "divorce" would cost half my current gold.

The same friend told me that I should use up as much of my gold as possible to minimize my loss, but I don't see anything sensible to buy with my ~200K gold.

Is there any other way to split up with my current wife in a less painful manner? Is there a point in the game where really expensive and worthwhile things show up and I should just manage until there?

I'm not beyond editing my save files to alleviate this issue, so if you know how to do that, I'm game.

Comment: http://moms4mom.com

Comment: Ah, King's Bounty the Legend. The Nethack of Heroes of Might and Magic style games.

Comment: Also, for reference, [here's a list of the potential children for each wife and their effect](http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showthread.php?t=4559). As you can see, some of the bonuses are really, really good.

Comment: It looks like [the site](http://www.kings-bounty.com/) is down. Is the company/game still around and available?

Comment: @echoback wrong site mate. http://www.kingsbountygame.com/

Comment: @JamesJiao Appreciated! But even that official site links to [a broken page](http://www.kings-bounty.com/eng/legend/) on the "kings-bounty.com" domain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I loved [the game](http://legend.kingsbountygame.com/)! You should include links for the game so others can [find out more about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Bounty:_The_Legend).

Anyway, the answer:

```
SHIFT + ` 
clearwife
```

--via [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939197-kings-bounty-the-legend/46088875)

You can read more on the [GameFAQs cheat page](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/939197-kings-bounty-the-legend/cheats).

Your friend was correct about that being the only option in-game.

Comment: You are correct, the link explains that, so I didn't bother putting the details here, since it was the short answer :).

Answer (score 16):

Remember that if you get to level 3 of the selling skill (which gives 100% of the item's value when selling it), you can just buy whatever you like, divorce her, and then sell what you bought for the full amount you spent. So what you buy doesn't have to be sensible.

That's what I did - bought items and spell scrolls until I got practically nothing left, divorced her, then sold it all back. 50% of nothing is nothing. Just remember to remove all items from her slots first, otherwise she will take those away with her when she goes.

Comment: I don't think I really have the mind runes to spare for this approach, but if I were a paladin it would definitely be viable.